# How Do I Rewrite A URL With htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a have a portal for a website I am making and it is to be setup to valormc.us/index.html but I would like it to be valormc.us without a redirect just the domain plain I have tried everything but it does not seem to work for some reason I am a noob with this type of stuff but I would like to learn!

I have tried

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^=]+)=(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/ /index.html [R=301,L,NC]

# Now, deal with internal rewrites (which will not cause redirection):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ucp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ / [NC,L]
```

I also tried

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: Share what you tried and what happened when it didn't work.

Comment: Update your question with this information. Make sure you format the information correctly so it's readable. The sample you shared doesn't look like it has anything to do with what you're trying to do though, so I would also recommend you find a tutorial and try it from scratch.

Comment: I have looked up online I tried a generator and it did not work and what I found I tried and it did not work or it was confusing

Comment: I also just tried another thing I found online and it still did not work

Comment: Well, it is a programming forum. You're not gonna get much help if you use an 'online generator'. You have to try to understand each line in your .htaccess configuration and know *why* you wrote it. If you don't, it will also be hard to ask questions on a programming forum. The first block in particular has *nothing* to do with what you're asking.